# condition statement without if and switch

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean greeting = true;        //or false
    if(greeting)
        hello();
}

public static void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello")
}
```

I want to call hello method without using (if,switch) if the value of greeting is set to true

is it possible to re-write this program without using if statement or switch ? if so how?

Comment: What's wrong with having `if`?

Comment: nothing wrong , but this question I had been asked but could not answer

Comment: @Maroun It is a common school problem meant to make sure people learn more about their programming language.

Comment: @EdwinBuck too bad schools focus on the wrong things. I don't see what value this will problem gives.

Comment: @Maroun I agree, any school that asks this question thinks it is teaching something, but really they could have just asked "did you read about the ternary operatior?" instead of trying to be clever by tricking the student into thinking this is an advanced technique.

Comment: It's good to learn alternatives and explore what the language has to offer, but as you see, none of the answers given so far is better than a single `if`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner even the question from the OP is : **if** *the value of greeting is set to true*

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That's because `if` already was the simplest technique to solve the problem.  This is like asking "if you don't have a glass of water, how could you drink a container of water?"  Basically you'll mostly get answers that all resemble calling the container something other than a glass.  But, at the end of the day, a wooden bucket of water just seems like a big, wood, glass! :)

Comment: @Eugene Good catch! :P We should ask the OP (and OP's professor as well) to ask this question without using the **if** word. Maybe it's a good way to learn that sometimes an `if` is just an `if`...

Comment: @EdwinBuck Yes, you are correct, of course... Almost anything can be used as a glass, I think. Or you could also dive your head into the container...

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `enum`

```
enum Greeting {
    GREETING(() -> System.out.println("hello")),
    NO_GREETING(() -> {});

    private final Runnable greeting;

    private Greeting(Runnable r) {
        greeting = r;
    }
    public void greet() {
        greeting.run();
    }
}
```

and then have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Greeting gr = Greeting.GREETING;   // or Greeting.NO_GREETING
    // or if you insist on the boolean
    // Greeting gr = (greeting) ? Greeting.GREETING : Greeting.NO_GREETING;
    gr.greet();
}
```

That would also be extendable to have things like

```
CORDIAL_GREETING(() -> System.out.println("hi wow so nice to see you"))
```

in the enum.

The ternary operator in the comment is of course not really different from an if/else.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean b = true;
    Predicate<Boolean> p = s -> {hello();return true;};
    boolean notUsefulVariable = b && p.test(true);      //will be called
    b = false;
    notUsefulVariable = b && p.test(true);              //will not called


}

public static void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

or you could use `while`

```
b = true;
while(b)
{
    hello();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean greeting = true;        //or false
    while(greeting) {
        hello();
        break;
    }
}
```

It may not be very elegant, but that wasn't the question, and it's the simplest solution (at least, that I can think of).

Answer (score 1):

If modification of `greet()` is allowed, one can do it with very little changes to the original code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean greet = true;
    boolean dummy = greet && greet();
}

public static boolean greet() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to branch into a block of code without an if statement.  I'll start with simple, and move to the complex.

1. You can use a `switch` statement.  It is basically a compound `if`statement, with more conditions.
2. You can use the ternary operator `?`.  This replaces the condition with one of two values, and can be used like an `if` statement.
3. You can use conditional jumping.  Basically you store the body of the block of code for each result of the condition as the value in a `Map`, with the key being the value of the evaluated condition.  Then you evaluate the condition, and run the code.  For example

   myMap.get(age > 3).execute();

Where `myMap` is a Map with

```
 Map(true) = block of code to `execute()` if true.
 Map(false) = block of code to `execute()` if false.
```

There's lots of ways to go about it.  These are just some common ones.

--- Edited with example, as Przemysław Moskal asked for one :) ---

I see your confusion about ternary and returning `null`, but the poster isn't going to print `null` in either case of their conditional, they are going to print a `String`.

```
public class Hello {

  private static Map<Boolean, String> response;


  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // setup the response map
     response = new HashMap<>();
     response.put(Boolean.TRUE, "Hello");
     response.put(Boolean.FALSE, "");

     boolean value = true;
     System.out.println(response.get(value));
  }

}
```

or another approach

```
public class Hello {

  private static Map<Boolean, Runnable> response;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // setup the response map
     response = new HashMap<>();
     response.put(Boolean.TRUE, new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hello");
       }
     });
     response.put(Boolean.FALSE, new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
       }
     })

     boolean value = true;
     response.get(value).run();
  }

}
```

or anther example

```
System.out.println((condition) ? "Hello" : "");
```

However, it is quite possible for a ternary operation to return `null`.

```
(condition) ? null : "hi";
```

is a valid expression, provided that the `null` or the `hi` are both valid in the context of where you write that expression.

Comment: `switch` is not to be used. See in the question.

Comment: @cst1992 Ah, didn't read down that far.  I'm leaving it in for completeness, even if it was explicitly excluded.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Correct me if I&#39;m wrong but I&#39;m pretty sure you cannot assign method returning void as one of results of ternary operator. Both results need to be something other than void. It is main difference between if and ternary operators.

Comment: @EdwinBuck In OP's question there is method hello() called when variable holds true, but in your example in the comment you make a choose between "hardcoded" String or null. Could you provide an example how this ternary operator should be written in exactly OP's case? I can't figure it out :-/

Comment: @EdwinBuck By writing "in OP's case" I mean to call method returning void if condition in operand before "?"  is true. I don't see a possibility to do it the way you provided.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I feel it's not the point of that question to print some String, I think the point in this question was to call a method returning void when condition is fulfilled (I think that was the point, printing "Hello" to the console was just an example of executing something in body of method - this is admitted after OP's code example, not the ways of printing something). Thank you for editing your answer, but it doesn't cover OP's question IMHO. He asked for something like this *condition ? hello() : null* rather than *condition ?" Hello" : null*, but it seems impossible to me with ternary

Comment: @EdwinBuck "I want to call hello method without using (if,switch) if the value of greeting is set to true" - I don't see where in your examples you call hello() method with the use of ternary operator that you proposed in 2). You provide the same result (printing something to the console), but we can agree that there could be a lot of more things to do in hello() method body and ternary operator doesn't allow that in this case.

Comment: @EdwinBuck This question isn't currently proposed to be as a possible duplicate (at least I don't see that), I look at this as at a MVCE well prepared by OP and I still think that the solution provided by you is different to what OP was asking here (maybe your solution fits to questions you talk about, but I personally think it is not correct in this case although printing the same result to the console). Of course you are far more experienced than I am, but in this particular case, I need to stay unsatisfied with what was presented in this answer ;-) Wish you all the best!

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal "I need to stay unsatisfied"...  I bet you do.  You've taken nearly every explanation and found a way to remain unsatisfied.  Please take your discussion elsewhere, I have nothing that can override your need to stay unsatisfied.

Comment: @EdwinBuck My language skills are not at the highest level, sorry for that - I meant that it seems that it's hard for us to work out a compromise in this matter, as both of us see the OP's problem in a bit different way - it's not like that I  like to keep looking for a problem here, improving skills and sharing knowledge is a main priority here for me and I really (REALLY) was curious how is that possible to call that method with the use of ternary operator, that's it. I want to make you aware that this discussion's target was not to attack you - if you consider my comments as an appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I'm really sorry for that, it was not my intention (I feel a lot of respect to what you've achieved and what big part of SO community you are) . As an addition, I would like just to propose you to look at my answer, maybe you may find there what was I was thinking about talking with you about that ternary operator more or less.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal I understand that English is not everyone's primary language.  People suffer when I speak Spanish :).  This question is one I've answered here on StackOverflow in the past, and I never could find a good reason why it was even asked.  Mostly the askers never bothered to give their account a name, and the reputation was always under 100.  To me, this (and the question itself) sounds much like a homework problem / riddle.  I see your response, and will look at it.  No harm done! :)

Comment: @EdwinBuck Yeah, you're right this might be a homework, for sure. Anyway, sometimes these kind of problems make others look for some unconventional solutions to problem and this might lead to some really interesting conclusion - anyway, this time it seems that there is no better and simpler solution than simple if-else :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's **only** a **Compiler** trick question.

**Based on the question** : `greeting` is set to `true` **or** `false`, **not changeable vairable**.

If we set : `boolean greeting = true;`, the Compiler ignores `if` command and delete it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean greeting = true;
    // if(greeting)   ---ignores with Compiler
         hello();
}
```

However, if we set : `boolean greeting = false;`, the Compiler ignores all the `if` command as **Dead Code** and delete all the `if`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean greeting = false;
    // if(greeting)   ---ignores with Compiler as Dead Code
    //     hello();   ---ignores with Compiler as Dead Code
}
```

**Therefor**: if `greeting` set to `true`: there is no need to `if`. And if `greeting` set to `false`: there is no need to `if` and `hello()` method. So there is not any `if` in the final code to change it to other things.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. In most cases, the boolean will not be a hardcoded value; it'll be a value passed to a function containing the code or an argument given to the program. Then the `if` absolutely will matter.

Comment: While there are optimizing compilers that can do this, not every compiler is optimizing, and even the optimizing ones can sometimes miss a seemingly simple optimization.  That said, if it was a compiler trick question, then I can't understand how "compare and jump" or "jump if zero" as an assembly language instruction would be considered "not if" unless it's a really lame compiler trick question, where the punchline is that it's not "if" in the C language.

Answer (score -1):

As my first attempt to answer this question was not well received, I tried to make another one.

After a little discussion under one of the answers to this question, I was looking for a way to use ternary operator (`condition ? value1 : value2`) to call method whose return value is `void` and I think it's rather impossible, because `value1` and `value2` can't be result of calling such method as `hello()` returns nothing. If there is a need to use ternary operator, I guess this is the only possible way to make use of this operator, with making the least additional operations possible:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean greeting = true;        //or false
        checkIfGreetingIsTrue(greeting);
    }

    public static void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static Void checkIfGreetingIsTrue(boolean greeting) {
        return greeting ? callHelloInMyBody() : null;
    }

    public static Void callHelloInMyBody() {
        hello();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah instead of returning the value, you print the function as a side-effect of evaluating the ternary operator.  Of course, this works; however if interpreted "returns true" as the Java boolean `true` this doesn't return anything as void must return null.  One can simplify this by not putting the ternary in a function, but your function naming makes things extra clear.   Nice!   Meanwhile, I'll never avoid an `if` statement; because, that's silly.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Thank you for time you've spent to look at it and for saying what you think about it. Of course, I agree with you that there is nothing more simple and easy than if statement in that situation. My goal was just to: 1) Call void method, 2) try to use ternary operator some way to achieve that, 3) try to make the code as close as it is possible to the original code without using if(). But I need to admit - that was just to try it, not to prove it's a solution than using if() :-)